# Android textview - i cannot get it going

Tags: java, android, textview

Hi Iam trying to build my first android project. I am quiete a good programmer, for microcontrollers, php, bash etc.

However this java syntax is making want to explode.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText("Text2");

}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable = "true" />
```

I checked many examples on the web but it looks like i cannot get it going.

`tv1.setText("Text2");`  always comes up as syntax error.

Where am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initialize after setContentView
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText("Text2"); // should be within a method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you code in Java every line of code needs to be inside a method (except for variable declarations). The code when you want to initialize your `TextView` is not inside a method which causes the error.

Change your code to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText("Text2");
}
```

This causes that the initialization of your TextView is done inside the onCreate method which is the method that is called when the view is created.

If you want to use the TextView later on, too, move the variable declaration of tv1 outside the method.

```
private TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText("Text2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are placing

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText("Text2");
```

outside of any method in your MainActivity class. Just place those 2 lines INSIDE onCreate() method, after setContentView().